# EPSON RECEIPT PRINTER in JAVA

Tags: java, epson, javapos

I install epson printer driver and also epson javapos apd
program compile successfully it get exception runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" jpos.JposException: Could not connect to service with
logicalName = EPSON TM-U220 Receipt: Exception.message=Could not create service instance.
    at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(Unknown Source)
    at Test4.main(Test4.java:17)
```

My jpos.xml file in same directory it contains following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE JposEntries PUBLIC "-//JavaPOS//DTD//EN" "jpos/res/jcl.dtd">
<JposEntries>
<!--Saved by JavaPOS jpos.config/loader (JCL) version 2.2.0 on 9/30/13 12:40 PM-->
<JposEntry logicalName="EPSON TM-U220 Receipt">
    <creation factoryClass="jp.co.epson.uposcommon.util.EpsonJposServiceInstanceFactory" serviceClass="jp.co.epson.upos.pntr.U220DService"/>
    <vendor name="SEIKO EPSON" url="http://www.epson.com"/>
    <jpos category="POSPrinter" version="1.11"/>
    <product description="EPSON TM-U220D Printer Device Service" name="EPSON Services for JavaPOS(TM) Standard" url="http://www.epson.com"/>
    <!--Other non JavaPOS required property (mostly vendor properties and bus specific properties i.e. RS232 )-->
    <prop name="Halftone" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PhysicalPrinterName" type="String" value="EPSON TM-U220 Receipt"/>
    <prop name="NVRAMControlLevel" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="Stamp" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="OutputCompleteType" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="StatusThreadInterval" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="OutputTimeout" type="String" value="500"/>
    <prop name="PortType" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="OutputBufferSize" type="String" value="65536"/>
    <prop name="FirmRecordLog" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="UsedNVRAM" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="ReceiveTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="SlpReverseEject" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PortName" type="String" value="ESDPRT001"/>
    <prop name="OfflineRetryIntervalTime" type="String" value="25"/>
    <prop name="DefaultSlpClampTime" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="epson.trace.file" type="String" value="trace.log"/>
    <prop name="AsyncProcessingSize" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="KanjiTwoWaysPrint" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PulseStep" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="PortInterfaceName" type="String" value="USB"/>
    <prop name="OutPipe" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="U375Compatible" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PortNameType" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="preCutterFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="epson.tracing" type="String" value="false"/>
    <prop name="epson.trace.max.size" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="RecPaperSize" type="String" value="76"/>
    <prop name="DeviceDesc" type="String" value="EPSON TM-U220D POSPrinter"/>
    <prop name="PageModeExt" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="SupportStatistics" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="OutputErrorOption" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="FirmProgressRange" type="String" value="10"/>
    <prop name="SupportFirmware" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InputTimeout" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="AutoPowerOff" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="SlpMoreColumns" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="RecPaperType" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="MemorySwitch" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="ReadThreadInterval" type="String" value="-1"/>
    <prop name="QueuingOfflineTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="TwoColor" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InitializeThreadTime" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="TwoByteCharacter" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="FirmLogFileSize" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="Peeler" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InPipe" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="ConfigurationFile" type="String" value="epson/xml/Setting/TM U220DSetting.xml"/>
    <prop name="Custom1Color" type="String" value="0xFF0000"/>
    <prop name="preEndorseFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="Upos.Spec_c" type="String" value="false"/>
    <prop name="FirmNotifyAllProgressEvents" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InitializeResponseTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="ReceiveRetryTime" type="String" value="25"/>
    <prop name="UsedInterCharacterSet" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="RecMoreColumns" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PrinterTransmitTimeout" type="String" value="30000"/>
    <prop name="WriteThreadInterval" type="String" value="-1"/>
    <prop name="preORCBFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="RecNearEndSensor" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="LogObject" type="String" value=""/>
    <prop name="Cutter" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PhysicalDevice" type="String" value="TM-U220D"/>
    <prop name="FirmLogFileName" type="String" value="Firmware.log"/>
    <prop name="UsedPeeler" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InputBufferSize" type="String" value="4096"/>
    <prop name="TransmitTimeout" type="String" value="5000"/>
    <prop name="OfflineCount" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="TransmitRetryTime" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="DirectIOEventTimeout" type="String" value="5000"/>
```

What is missing I install all required jars and added to the classpath
please help
yhank in advance

Comment: Check this question for correct setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839049/how-can-i-use-javapos-to-print-reciepts-with-an-epson-printer/30839050

Answer (score 1):

Most of those peripherals require .dlls as well to work, have you installed those in the correct location (check your documentation for details)