# Epson JavaPOS ADK install - Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM

Tags: java, epson, javapos

I recently bought an Epson TM-T20II thermal receipt printer for a POS application I'm developing. Whenever I try to install the JavaPOS ADK from the Epson site (Or the included software cd, for that matter) I get `Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM`.

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839050/4385713) but that leaves me with another error: `ZeroGr2: Windows DLL failed to load`

[image: another error :(]

I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 and have installed the anniversary update.

Any help on resolving this error and getting the installation to complete would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the Windows error 2 code, start the .exe from the command prompt(as admin) and add a paramater LAX_VM, so something like

> > Epson_JavaPOS_ADK_1141.exe LAX_VM "C:\Java\jre\bin\java.exe"

I think the second problem is because of an issue with the Java 8 64-bit JRE. I can reproduce that error with the 64-bit jre1.8.0_101 but using the 32-bit version works fine. I also tried it with a 64-bit JRE7 and that worked as well.

Edit: it seems you need to start the command prompt as admin as well.

Comment: I did indeed try that command to get it to work. The problem is that whatever JRE I use (I've tried java 7 and 8 both x32 and x64), I always get that error.

Comment: One thing I also did was to run the command prompt as admin. Have you tried that with the different JREs?

Comment: I also remember setting the compatibility mode to Windows 7, but I don't know if that has any effect if you run it from the command prompt. Unfortunately I don't have anything else :(

Comment: I got it to install by issuing the command you said in an administrator command prompt and using the 64-bit Java 7 jre.

Comment: Alright, so now it's installed. Though IntelliJ doesn't understand the references. I tried adding the installed files as dependency but can't find them (IntelliJ only takes .jar files it seems, while the installer created some .dll files).. I copied the files into the ext folder of every jdk and jre I have but it still can't find it..

Comment: Good to hear it is installed at least! For IntelliJ to recognize the classes you need to add it as a library. If you don't use Maven, you can go to File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Click on Plus icon. The library you want is jpos113.jar which should be installed in your JRE/lib/ext folder by the installer.

Comment: Thanks. I do use Maven, but simply adding jpos as dependency doesn't work because the Epson sample code still can't find all required classes.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to install the Epson JavaPOS ADK, I end up with the two same errors :

- `Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM`
- then `ZeroGr2: Windows DLL failed to load`

I manage to make it work by :

- Launching the installer with @TrollGate's LAX_VM parameter :  i.e.  : `Epson_JavaPOS_ADK_1141.exe  LAX_VM "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe"` in a *admin* command terminal
- Using a 32 bits JVM : I used the 32 bits `jdk1.8.0_101`

I didn't need to launch the terminal as administrator to make it work, but **the installation manual states that it should be run with administrator's privilege**.
I didn't need to change the compatibility settings of the installer either.