# JavaPOS not working on Epson TM-T20II outside Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, epson, javapos, netbeans-8.2

I have successfully integrated JavaPos to my java (JavaFX) app, tested it and it works with the device.

Now the problem is that the application cannot identify the printer if I execute the application outside the Netbeans 8.2 IDE.

This is the error I get:

> Sat May 19 10:48:47 GMT 2018,INFO,jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService,createCommInstance,2907,Could not create an instance.

I have investigated on possible solution to this but to no avail. I even found a solution here [setting us javapos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839049/how-can-i-use-javapos-to-print-reciepts-with-an-epson-printer) which did work for me during the development, but that was it.

My question is, how can I make the application work with the device outside Netbeans?

Comment: Not enough information. Please share the relevant part of the code and any exception messages, stack traces etc. that you have.

Comment: Are you creating this object, or is something doing it for you? If the former, then @RobinGreen is correct, and readers would need to see more code.

Comment: The question I would like to see an answer to is what does Netbeans do for you with its development environment that you have to do for yourself outside of Netbeans. For instance is there a classpath issue or something like that?

Comment: Problems like this (application works inside IDE, but not outside) are often caused by not understanding how resources work in Java. Resources need to be put in `src/main/resources` (assuming a standard Maven-style project structure).

Comment: I will try that out and see

Answer (score 0):

Install `javaPOS` version `1.14.6`.

On windows 10 or 8.1 copy:

```
BluetoothIO.DLL
epsonjpos.dll
EthernetIO31.DLL
SerialIO31.dll
USBIO31.DLL
```

from `C:\Program Files\EPSON\JavaPOS\bin\` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0.171\bin\`

Import lib to your project from `C:\Program Files\EPSON\JavaPOS\lib\`

Run javaPOS application.